# send mail from application through other smtp server 25

Tags: php, linux, smtp

I'm facing below problem:
rcpt to: *toxxxx@smtphost.com* 454 4.7.1 *toxxxx@smtphost.com*

```html
I'm facing below problem: telnet 10.5.2.28 25  Trying 11.1.2.21... Connected to 11.1.2.21. Escape character is... 220 smtp04.smtphost.com ESMTP Postfix HELO 171.21.1.21(application server) 250 smtp04.smtphost.com mail from: fromxxx@smtphost.com 250 2.1.0 Ok rcpt to: toxxxx@smtphost.com 454 4.7.1 <toxxxx@smtphost.com>: Relay access denied
```

: Relay access denied

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

The SMTP server that you are connecting to is not the MX for the recipient that you are trying to send the message to.  So, to send the message, the SMTP server that you are connecting to would have to `relay` the message.  The error that you are getting  `Relay access denied` indicates that the SMTP server will not relay the message.

Did you authenticate with the SMTP server that you are connecting to?  If not, then it's not surprising that you are seeing this error message, as otherwise this would be an [open relay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_mail_relay), and would probably quickly be abused by spammers.